# Joint filtration of two right-continuous filtrations is right-continuous?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Assume we are given two right-continuous filtrations $\mathbb{F}^X=(\mathcal{F}_t^X)$ and $\mathbb{F}^Y=(\mathcal{F}_t^Y)$ both generated by some stochastic processes $X, Y$. Do we have that the joint filtration $\mathbb{F}^{X,Y}$ is right-continuous?

Answer (score 1):

(I assume $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued and right continuous.) Not necessarily. For example, the event
$$
\eqalign{
C
&=\cap_n[\{\omega: X_t(\omega)-Y_t(\omega)>0\hbox{ for some }t\in(0,1/n)\}\cr
&\phantom{bbbbbbb}\cap\{\omega: X_t(\omega)-Y_t(\omega)<0\hbox{ for some }t\in(0,1/n)\}],\cr
}
$$
that $X-Y$ changes sign infinitely often just after time 0, is $\mathcal F^{X,Y}_{0+}$-measurable, but not $\mathcal F^X_0\vee \mathcal F^Y_0$-measurable.

Nonetheless, the  filtration $\mathcal F_t^X\vee\mathcal F_t^Y$, $t\ge 0$, *is* right continuous (modulo null sets) when $X$ and $Y$ are *independent*.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last statement? Can one say anything general if $X$-is real-valued and right continuous and $Y$ is a non-explosive step process (thus the example you gave isn't a problem)?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the right continuity of $\Bbb F^{X,Y}$ was true when $X$ is a right-continuous step process.

Comment: What if $X$ wasn’t a stochastic process but just a random variable? Will we have that the filtration $\sigma(X) \vee \mathcal{F}^Y_t$ is right continuous for $Y_t$ a step process with right continuous filtration?

Answer (score 1):

**Added detail:** If $G$ is bounded and $\mathcal F^X_\infty\vee\mathcal F^Y_\infty$ measurable, then $E[G\mid\mathcal F^{X,Y}_{t+}]=\lim_nE[G\mid\mathcal F^{X,Y}_{t+1/n}]$, almost surely,  by martingale convergence. If also $G=G_1(X)G_2(Y)$ then by independence this limit is a.s. equal to $\lim_nE[G_1(X)\mid\mathcal F^X_{t+1/n}]\cdot E[G_2(Y)\mid\mathcal F^Y_{t+1/n}]
=E[G_1(X)\mid\mathcal F^X_{t}]\cdot E[G_2(Y)\mid\mathcal F^Y_{t}]$ by the rt-continuity of $\Bbb F^X$ and $\Bbb F^Y$. That is, $E[G\mid \mathcal F^{X,Y}_{t+}]=E[G\mid \mathcal F^{X,Y}_{t}]$, almost surely,  for $G$ of the special form $G_1(X)G_2(Y)$. This equality persists for general $G$ by the monotone class theorem.